# Display React components in a row

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I am new to React and I am trying to display an array of details in a row. I am using MaterialUI. I have a separate component **(MovieListItem)** which displays the details. This component is being rendered by another component **(MoviesList)**.

I want the details in the MovieListItem to appear in a single row. In this code they are appearing in different rows. Possibly because the child component is being returned for every item in the array.

**MoviesList:**

```
const MoviesList = (props) => (
    <div>
        <div>
            <h1>Movies</h1>
        </div>
        {
            props.details.map((detail) => {
                return <MovieListItem key={detail.id} {...detail} />
            })
        }
    </div>
)
```

**MovieListItem:**

```
const MovieListItem = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                        <h4><b>Title: {props.title}</b></h4>
                        <p>Description : {props.description}</p>
                    </Paper>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Add `display: inline-block;` to your `classes.root`

Answer (score 4):

```
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
const MoviesList = (props) => (
    <div>
        <div>
            <h1>Movies</h1>
        </div>
        <Box display="flex">
        {
            props.details.map((detail) => {
                return <MovieListItem key={detail.id} {...detail} />
            })
        }
        </Box>
    </div>
)
```

Simply wrap your list items in Box component with display as flex, it will by default display items in a row. You can also add `flexWrap` property if you want to wrap content automatically when content can't fit in a single row

Comment: This works to a certain level. The distance between each Paper element becomes unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these css values to the class you're giving to MovieListItem (classes.root) :

```
.movies-list-item {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content: flex-start; //you can change it depends on what you exactly need
}
```